# How make batch size Optimum for inference ASR model on GPU

Tags: gpu, torch, transformer-model, whisper

I had trained a `Whisper ASR model` and I have `8Gb GPU memory`, my model take `4Gb` of my GPU and I have to calculate the maximum batch size to fit to the model and get the transcribes because my data are around **200k each hour** and I have to make it as fastest as possible
and my total Parameters of my model is `763857920`

I tried to use 10 audio and I got the `CUDA out of ...`, the data was like this:

```
Chunk-Size------1.38Mb
chunk-len-------9
GPU-free(Mb)----3777.94MB
gpu-util--------1700.00%
gpu-mem---------200.00%
ERROR-message---Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB
```